# Excel VBA merge two columns

Tags: excel, merge, vba

So basically, I figured out the code to merge column A and B. This might seem silly, but no matter how many times I change the X value or the cell numbers I can't figure out for the life of me how to merge columns K and L.

here's what I did to merge A&B. Basically I want to merge first and last name but they're located in columns K and L. Feel free to tell me if there's an easier way to merge columns using VBA. I'm new to this..

```
Sub MergeColumns()
Dim myText As String, mySpace As String
mySpace = " "

Cells(1, 1) = "AuthorText"
Cells(1, 2) = ""

x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
Cells(x, 1) = Cells(x, 1) & mySpace & Cells(x, 2)
Cells(x, 2) = ""
x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells has two arguments. The first is the row, the second is the column. If you want to combine the text from columns K and L, then use the appropriate numbers.

`cells(2,11)` will address cell K2.

[image]